# What game is this person playing from a suitcase in this Tiktok video?

Tags: game-identification

What is the name of this game that this person is playing in this
[Tiktok video](https://vm.tiktok.com/ZGeyssAjL)?

An image taken from the video can be found below:

[image: image from video]

Answer (score 18):

It’s hard to say for certain due to the quality, but that looks like [*Stranger of Paradise: Final Fantasy Origin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_of_Paradise:_Final_Fantasy_Origin). Particularly the [Fused Elemental](https://youtu.be/hrxF07j9_3s?si=zbi-afUCRwUf5EDq) boss:

[image: screenshot from the linked gameplay video]

Comment: I'd say that's a match